# What is the difference between a "pamfleto" and a "faldfolio"?

Tags: word-choice

I emailed some people a while back about *pamfletoj* (thanks to lernu's vortaro), and all of them changed the word to *faldfolioj* in their responses. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIV defines *pamfleto* as *Verketo, en kiu oni akre atakas iun aŭ ion* - J.C. Wells' dictionary defines it in English as "lampoon". It is a false friend, meaning that it sounds like the English word but means something different. (However, according to Google Translate "pamphlet" means "lampoon" in French, which is probably where the Esperanto word came from.)

J.C. Wells' dictionary says "pamphlet" translates to *broŝuro*, which PIV defines as *Presaĵo, ĝenerale ne dika, kies kajeroj estas kunkudritaj k ne binditaj*. *Broŝuro* occurs 100+ times in Tekstaro.com, while *faldfolio* appears only 16 times. This tells me that *broŝuro* is at least more common if not preferred.

Note that, according to a quick Google search, the English words "pamphlet" and "brochure" are used mostly interchangeably though there is a slight technical difference in how they are folded (or something?). J.C. Wells defines "brochure" as *broŝur(et)o* or *prospekto*.

Comment: There is also the word _flugfolio_ which has 47 results in Tekstaro.

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia and Lernu define that as "flyer" which may work as well.